# Hack N Slash movement animation - how to end animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

Im quite new to animation in Unity, does anybody know how in this loop I can set my bool to false when my Character will arrive at destination point? Most help I found on Internet was about controling your charracter with keyboard, but mine is conntroled by mouse clicks only.

```
    {
    Camera cam;
    Animator  animator;



    NavMeshAgent agent;


private void Start()
{
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    cam =  GameObject.Find("Main Camera").gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
    agent = this.gameObject.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
}




private void Update()
{
    
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
          animator.SetBool("Isrunning", true);
       
    
     if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
                agent.SetDestination(hit.point);  
             
                
  
             }
 

    }
   
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(agent.remainingDistance < 0.1)
{
  animator.SetBool("...", false);
}
```